# How to create predicate to fetch core data entities by string property sorted as an integer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I simply have a `Month` entity with property

```
@objc(Month)
class Month: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var identifier: String //202311, 202301, 201912 and so on, always year and month as a components
}
```

Now I need to fetch all months with identifier between given start and end, for example predicate format:

```
"identifier >= 202306 AND identifier <= 202311"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It depends. I guess the logic is "yyyyMM", so if there are always the same number of characters, ie "000301" (if possible), a simple comparison should work as String. Else, I'm wondering if `identifier.intValue` might work too. And it's about sort or filtering?

Comment: @Larme, of course‍♂️ it worked as String... there is always the same number of characters;) Thank you... I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the format `yyyyMM`, so in fact, you can use the String comparison: same count of numbers for each unit (leading zeros if needed), and largest (year) to smallest (month).

If you had no leading zero for months, and/or for year, it wouldn't have worked, but in your case, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `<=` and `<` should work.